# Do both superiority dice from Superior Technique and Martial Adept only increase die size when a character reaches 10th level Battlemaster?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, class-feature, fighter, battle-master

Also, does that mean that dice gained from either of these features never become d8's?

Comment: This might be a duplicate: [Does the Martial Adept superiority dice scale up alongside the Battle Master fighter's superiority dice if you acquire the subclass after the feat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/104360)

Comment: I would argue that this very much is not a duplicate - the linked question is about how Improved Combat Superiority at level 10+ interacts with Martial Adept, but it doesn't cover how they interact with the Combat Superiority feature itself - does a level 3 battlemaster with the aforementioned feat have 4 d8s and 1 d6, or do they have 5 d6es?