# In D&D 5e, does the superiority dice from the new superior technique fighting style become a d8 if you are a battlemaster?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, fighter, fighting-style, battle-master

I was just wondering if it functions the same as the martial adept feat's dice, which do become d8s as confirmed by Jeremy Crawford.
https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/1250815333331382274?lang=en

Comment: Also a dupe: "[Do both superiority dice from Superior Technique and Martial Adept only increase die size when a character reaches 10th level Battlemaster?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/178394)"

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se, Mike! We have closed your question as a duplicate, as it has been asked and answered before. This is a good thing, your question can serve as a sign post for users who find it first.

Comment: While you're here, check out the [tour] and the [help] for lots of useful information about our stack.

Comment: Well that question refers to the martial adept feat. I was curious about the Superior Technique fighting style that came out after that question was answered.